# Java 8 HttpClient 4.5 Which CookieSpecs should I use?

Tags: java, cookies, java-8, http-headers, apache-httpclient-4.x

I need to send cookie header in that format:

```
cookie: NAME=VALUE
cookie: NAME2=VALUE2
```

Which `CookieSpecs` should I use in `RequestConfig`?
There is:

- DEFAULT
- IGNORE
- NETSCAPE
- STANDARD
- STANDARD-STRICT

Answer (score 1):

You should be using either `STANDARD` or `STANDARD-STRICT` policy. As of version 5.0 `STANDARD` will also become the default.